# Use default parameter in JavaScript like in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

In C# you can do something like that:

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sum(2, 2, d: 10);
    }

    static int Sum(int a, int b, int c = 0, int d = 0)
    {
        return a + b + c + d;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar with Javascript?

```
const foo = (a, b, c = 0, d = 0) => a + b + c + d;
```

And then call this function:

```
foo(2, 2, d = 10);
```

Or the only way is call this function this way?

```
foo(2, 2, undefined, 10);
```

Comment: `const foo = ({a, b, c, d}) => { console.log(a, b, c, d); }; foo({a: 1, b: 2, d: 3});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do default parameters in JavaScript however there is no support for named parameters. So the arguments must follow the same order as parameters.

The javascript *alternative* is object destructuring:

```js
const foo = ({a, b, c = 0, d = 0}) => a + b + c + d;
```

Which you can then call "out of order" with:

```js
foo({b: 1, a: 2, d: 6})
```

Comment: thanks! When I saw this answer and drew a parallel with default props in React, I realized that the answer is very simple!

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you can do something like this:

```
const hello = (name = 'John Doe', b) => {
  console.log(`Hello Mr ${name}`);
};

hello('Jagathish'); // Hello Mr Jagathish
hello(); // Hello Mr John Doe
```